# Linear function $T$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $\lVert T(x)\rVert \geq c\lVert x\rVert$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a linear injective function,  then there exists $c>0$ such that $\lVert T(x)\rVert \geq c\lVert x\rVert, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I know some informations about linear injective function but I don't know how to build this proof.

I know that every linear transformation is continuous.
I know that if $T$ is injective then $\ker T=\{0\}$ and if $B$ is a basis of $T$, then $T(B)$ is a basis of the space $T(v)$.

But can you give me a tip? I don't know how to start it.

Comment: **Hint:** If $T$  is linear, $T$ is continuous. Then $T$ has a minimum in the unit sphere (because is compact).

Comment: I know how to prove in the unit sphere, How can I prove to $\mathbb{R}^m$??

Comment: So, for $x \neq 0$ you have $\left\|T\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)\right\| \geq c$ where $c$ is the minimum

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $T$ is injective if and only if for all $x \in \Bbb R^m$, $\|x\| = 1 \implies \|Tx\| \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take $c^{-1}=||A^{-1}||$, since we have
$$||x||=||A^{-1}Ax||\leq||A^{-1}||\cdot||Ax||$$